# Copy on write is an interesting idea used on server systems. Does it make any sense on a smartphone?

Tags: operating-systems

The data pages that are actually modified need to be copied. This approach, called copy on write, improves performance by reducing copying.

According to me it is unnecessary as every process has its own data. (not sure) A third process working with that data is really not possible.

Please tell me if it's possible, if possible then why? Also an example where this will be helpful would help.
Thank you.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks for the feedback. I added my answer to add my perspective on the question and not to check the correctness of the aforesaid answer. I am rewording the question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, copy-on-write makes sense on smartphones, too.  Smartphones are just computers, packaged to be small.  Smartphones run conventional operating systems, with multiple processes.  For instance, each app typically runs in its own process.  And yes, these processes do use shared memory, shared libraries, fork(), etc., so copy-on-write *is* useful (and *is* supported on typical smartphone operating systems).